# How to make toggle for iOS game to control movement?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm making an iOS game, and I want to be able to control the movement of my character with a toggle.

My idea is that when the user touches the screen with their thumb / finger, I will record where the touch began, and then whichever direction the users thumb is compared to where the touch began is the direction the character should move.

How could I setup a touch gesture recogniser to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it sounds to me like you are thinking of this at too high of a level. You don't need a "gesture recognition system" to do this. You know how to tell whether and where the touch is down? You know how to tell what time it is? Each time through your main loop, check if the touch is down / still down. When it first goes down, record the location and time. If later you see that it hasn't gone up and it's positioned a certain number of pixels to the right, you know it slid over there. And by comparing the times you know how fast it slid over there.

And of course you might want to check out Cocos2d for a library that does some of this for you. But it's worth doing yourself first, just to learn it.